# Geocoder.isPresent() undefined for the type Geocoder

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

My Android and Java skills aren't so hot...

In the developer.android.com page for Geocoder, it says :

> The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.

However, when I try to call, for example :

```
if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {...
```

Eclipse tells me

> The method isPresent() is undefined for the type Geocoder

How can I "use the isPresent() method"?

Comment: Have you imported the google maps api library? This will be helpful for you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Answer (score 3):

public static boolean isPresent () method only available from API level 9, It means you should use Android 2.3 or latter version for that. Make sure you are using that. Then check Eclipse project configuration for Android SDK.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html