# About google api called getFromLocationName()

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a question about the google api function called `getFromLocationName()`
I use the following code to put the address where I want to get the coordinates.

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(test.this, Locale.TAIWAN);
float add_lat=0,add_lot=0;
try {
      List addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);
      if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
      add_lat=(float) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude()*1E6);
      add_lot=(float) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude()*1E6);
      }
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I printed the values of coordinates,I always got zero point zero.
I don't know how to solve this problem,because it didn't get any error message when I compiled my code.
Please give me your point of views
Thanks :)

Comment: you must be giving wrong location name so that Geocoder is not able to get the lat lon.

Comment: Are running it in android application code?

Comment: To Sujit:I've tried many kinds of location names,but it didn't work. 
To sudmong:Yes,I run my code in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you should first check the presence of GeoCoder implementation and only then use it. It is not necessarily present in all devices.

> The Geocoder class requires a backend
>   service that is not included in the
>   core android framework. The Geocoder
>   query methods will return an empty
>   list if there no backend service in
>   the platform. Use the isPresent()
>   method to determine whether a Geocoder
>   implementation exists.

Comment: I've tried the method which you suggest.I couldn't find this function.I found a  
[page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707685/geocoder-ispresent-undefined-for-the-type-geocoder),it mentioned that it must be android 2.3.I use android 2.2 to develop my app.....

Comment: Hello,I've found another way to solve my problem.This [page](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) can teach you how to insert address and return json or xml values.It includes coordinates.I hope that this method will help people who have the same problem. :)